# Wpf No Highlight on ListBoxItem for Touch Devices

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

I have defined my ListBox to not show any highlight on the ListBoxItem as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
         Style="{x:Null}"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Button Content="{Binding SomeBinding}"/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Whilst this works on a desktop, as soon as I try running it on a touch device (e.g Microsoft Surface) I still get the default blue highlight on hover and selection. Any ideas what I'm missing for touch devices?

**Update**

Appears the easiest solution is to simply overwrite the style for the ListBoxItem, i.e.,

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="NonSelectingListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

although still not sure why setting the brushes as in the first section of xaml code above does not work on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

shall remove solidcolorbrush key values and give as ordinary key value.system colors may hold default colors and it produces blue highlight.

change your this part of code

```
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="Transparent"/>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand.